# C language: implicit pointer dereferencing

Tags: c

In C, is it possible to define an alias / shortcut for a dereferenced pointer?

I.e. assuming a definition like:

```
void * ptr_to_my_variable = 0x2ff00000;
```

Is it possible to define a `my_variable` symbol that corresponds to `*ptr_to_my_variable`, such that:

```
*ptr_to_my_variable = 321;
my_variable = 123;
if (my_variable == *ptr_to_my_variable) printf "aliasing/shortcut works";
```

The only solution I can think of is:

```
#define my_variable *my_variable
int my_variable = (int *) 0x2ff00000;

my_variable = 123;
```

But this is clearly asking for trouble...

Comment: May I ask why you need that (just curious)?

Comment: This would be a [reference in c++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)), but that feature doesn't really exist in c.

Comment: @arc_lupus I am reverse engineering some pieces of a larger program that makes use of existing global variables. Thus many location of the variables my function uses are fixed. This makes my code ugly and hard to understand: instead of writing `my_var = 1` it is littered with dereferencing stars `*my_var = 1`. This makes it difficult to distinguish from genuine pointer variables.

Comment: You can use your own solution and then use `#undef` to remove the shortcuts. This should make maintenance easier.

Comment: @Myst I don't think that scales. Assuming the `#define` above, and an additional `not_my_variable_two` symbol somewhere in the code, the preprocessor will transform this into: `not_*my_variable_two`!

Comment: @ARF -- no, the preprocessor only ever matches entire identifiers.  It will never match substrings of larger identifiers...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Ah... I did not realise that! So in your opinion, the `#define` solution does not land me in hell?

Comment: Well, casting a constant to a pointer and dereferencing it is always undefined, but may work if you have particular memory layout (eg, for an embedded processor).  The macro doesn't make things any worse.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I am indeed on an embedded processor with fixed memory layout. I was more thinking of unintended side-effects of the preprocessor but that seems to be not as big of an issue as I thought given that I am defining shortcuts for `global variables`. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: That is incorrect, it is not undefined behavior to convert an integer to a pointer.  See n1548 §6.3.2.3 ¶5: "An integer may be converted to any pointer type.  Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined..."

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The undefined behavbor happens when you dereference the pointer that doesn't point at anything.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: But whether the pointer does or does not point at anything is the result of implementation-defined behavior.  The part I'm responding to is "always undefined behavior", and that is not just "technically" incorrect in some sense but it is just completely incorrect.  How else are you supposed to access memory mapped registers anyway, for example?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: There is no standard-defined way of accessing memeory mapped registers -- you need an extension.  Any implementation is free to do anything it wants for anything that is undefined behavior, so it is free to define an extension that turns undefined behavior into defined behavior, but that's up to the implementation.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: The C standard explicitly distinguishes between undefined behavior and implementation-defined behavior.  You seem to be making the case that casting an integer constant to a pointer and dereferencing it is "always undefined behavior", this claim is flatly contradicted by the standard, in the quote above.  We're not even talking about extensions to the C standard.  Example: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Implementation.html - "A conforming implementation of ISO C is required to document its choice of behavior in each of the areas that are designated 'implementation defined'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no trick that would let you dereference a pointer implicitly.

However, preprocessor trick that youmentioned in the edit lets you hide the explicit dereference, making it look implicit:

```
#define my_alias (*my_var_ptr)
```

Note, however, that you should place parentheses around the expression, which wiuld save you from trouble when you write

```
my_alias++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the `#define` is the only way to do this in C.

C++ has things called "references" which are implicitly dereferenced, but can (must?) alias other objects. You'd have to ask somebody else about the details. But C does not support any such thing.